# module.exports in typescript

Tags: typescript, import, commonjs

does somebody know how to do a module.exports?

I tried some different ways ending up with

```js
export class Greeter {}
```

which will compile to

```js
exports.Greeter = Greeter;
```

But what I really want is this:

```
exports = Greeter;
```

So that I can use it like this:

```js
import { Greeter } from "greeter";

const greeter = new Greeter();
```

and not

```js
import { Greeter } from "greeter";

const greeter = new Greeter.Greeter();
```

Is this possible with Typescript?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can export a single class in TypeScript like this:

```
class Person {

  private firstName: string;
  private lastName: string;

  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public getFullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}

export = Person;
```

And here is how it's going to be used:

```
var Person = require('./dist/commonjs/Person.js');

var homer = new Person('Homer', 'Simpson');
var name = homer.getFullName();

console.log(name); // Homer Simpson
```

To be complete, here is my **tsconfig.json** (I am using TypeScript v2.0.3):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist/commonjs",
    "rootDir": "src/ts",
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wonder why typescript have not implement export Person ... bla bla bla ? I think it would be logical, no? or I am missing something?

Comment: Could it be possible to still export some typings from the file as well? You might want to get typings from the file in order to write tests, but still want a `module.exports` in the end.

Comment: It's indeed confusing, so I created a video explaining the differences in exports: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoOgNRQEYws

Answer (score 23):

This has now been implemented and is ready in TypeScript 0.9 :)

Comment: For clarification (since I had to go dig this up), the syntax in 0.9 is available here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/06/18/announcing-typescript-0-9.aspx (under "Export =").

Comment: And for further clarification, for future readers, it has been implemented **ALMOST** exactly as the asker desired . . . _But what I really want is_ `export = Greeter;`, that's exactly what you do :)

Comment: I wanted to just expose a config object from `config/db.ts` and use that configuration in app. This is what I could do successfully in TypeScript 1.4: In `config/db.ts` write `var config = {connStr:'postgres://user:pass@host/dbname'}; export = config;` and in `app.ts` refer it as `import dbConfig = require('./config/db'); dbConnect(dbConfig.connStr);`

Answer (score 10):

So I think I've found a workaround. Just wrap the keyword 'module' in parentheses in your .ts file:

```
declare var module: any;
(module).exports = MyClass;
```

The generated javascript file will be exactly the same:

```
(module).exports = MyClass;
```

Note, better than declaring var module yourself, download the [node.d.ts definition file](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) and stick it in the same directory as your typescript file. Here is a complete sample of an express node.js routing file which assumes node.d.ts is in same directory:

```
/// <reference path="node.d.ts" />
var SheetController = function () {
    this.view = function (req, res) {
        res.render('view-sheet');
    };
};
(module).exports = SheetController;
```

I can then new up a SheetController and (using express) assign the view method:

```
var sheetController = new SheetController();
app.get('/sheet/view', sheetController.view);
```

I suppose any keyword can be escaped using this pattern:

```
declare var reservedkeyword: any;
(reservedkeyword).anything = something;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's ugly and hacky, but you can still do:

```
class Greeter {}
declare var exports:any;
exports = Greeter;
```

Which compiles into:

```
var Greeter = (function () {
    function Greeter() { }
    return Greeter;
})();
exports = Greeter;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the TypeScript compiler doesn't seem to handle this well. For instance you can't derive from the class when you do this.

Comment: how would this work? Isn't that the whole argument with CommonJs vs. AMD. That Common doesn't support returning stuff directly as the exports variable?