# Typescript definition file using reserved keywords

Tags: typescript

How can I create a type definition for a function (global scope) named as a reserved keyword such as "module" (qunit, http://api.qunitjs.com/module/)?

Is there a prefix char or something I can use? A char that simply gets removed on compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do this currently - there is nothing like CoffeeScripts back-tick syntax.

One work-around would be to create a function in your JavaScript to alias the module function:

JavaScript

```
function moduleAlias(name, lifecycle) {
    module(name, lifecycle);
}
```

TypeScript

```
declare var moduleAlias: { (name: string, lifecycle: any) : void; };

moduleAlias('Test', {});
```

Answer (score 3):

I also think there is no way for this. In these cases you can use something like:

```
QUnit.module('module_name');
```

I'm working on a qunit.d.ts file on [this link](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/qunit/qunit.d.ts). With it you can use the code I put above.

Answer (score 0):

As per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14098120/131578) this works for me:

```
declare var module: any;
(module).exports = MyClass;
```