# Trying to create a declaration file for an existing API

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a definition file for an [existing nmp module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/claudia-api-builder).

Basically, this module exports one main function:

```
module.exports = function ApiBuilder(options) {...}
```

In its simple form, it is used like this:

```
var ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder'),
  api = new ApiBuilder();

module.exports = api;

api.get('/hello', function () {
  return 'hello world';
});
```

I've created a simple definition file like the following:

```
declare module "claudia-api-builder" {

    export class ApiBuilder {
        constructor(options?: any);

        get(uri: string, callback: Function): void;

    }
}
```

The following source .ts code:

```
import { ApiBuilder } from 'claudia-api-builder';

const api = new ApiBuilder();

api.get('/hello', function () {
    return 'hello world';
});

export default api;
```

Is transpiled to the following javascript (es2016):

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const claudia_api_builder_1 = require("claudia-api-builder");
const api = new claudia_api_builder_1.ApiBuilder();
api.get('/hello', function () {
    return 'hello world';
});
exports.default = api;
```

The above code fails with the the following error:

> claudia_api_builder_1.ApiBuilder is not a constructor

Of course, the transpiled code shoud have been:

```
const api = new claudia_api_builder_1();
```

Obviously, I'm missing the point here.
Any help appreciated.

**EDIT 1**: Solved the problem with the following index.d.ts file:

```
declare module "claudia-api-builder" {

    /*~ This declaration specifies that the class constructor function
     *~ is the exported object from the file
     */
    export = ApiBuilder;

    /*~ Write your module's methods and properties in this class */
    class ApiBuilder {
        constructor(options?: any);

        get(uri: string, callback: Function): void;
    }

}
```

Now the transpilation process gives me:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const ApiBuilder = require("claudia-api-builder");
const api = new ApiBuilder();
api.get('/hello', function () {
    return 'hello world';
});
exports.default = api;
```

The remaining problem here is that I need to replace:

> export default api;

in the typescript code to have

> module.exports = api;

generated by the transpilation process

Comment: Try `export default class ApiBuilder` and `import * as ApiBuilder from 'claudia-api-builder'`

Comment: unfortunately with your suggestion, I have the following: error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, problem solved.

First, I've found what I needed in the [Typescript documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html).
This helped me choose the template to start with:

> Use [module-class.d.ts](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html) if your module can be constructed using new:

The declaration file is now:

```
declare module "claudia-api-builder" {

    /*~ This declaration specifies that the class constructor function
     *~ is the exported object from the file
     */
    export = ApiBuilder;

    /*~ Write your module's methods and properties in this class */
    class ApiBuilder {
        constructor(options?: any);

        get(uri: string, callback: Function): void;
    }

}
```

And the ts source file has become :

```
import ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder');

const api = new ApiBuilder();

api.get('/hello', function () {
    return 'hello world';
});

export = api;
```

Thanks to this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17363932/15186) on SO.

For completeness, following is my tsconfig.json:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        /* Basic Options */
        "target": "es2016", /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
        "module": "commonjs", /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    output to single file. */
        "outDir": "./dist/", /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
        "rootDir": "./src/", /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
/* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
        /* Module Resolution Options */
        "moduleResolution": "node", /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
        "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
      }
    }
```

And finally, the transpiled code:

```
"use strict";
const ApiBuilder = require("claudia-api-builder");
const api = new ApiBuilder();
api.get('/hello', function () {
    return 'hello world';
});
module.exports = api;
```