# How to write a class compatible with nest & express

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I use typescript to write a tool class. I want to use it in express and nestjs respectively. My tool looks like this。

```js
export class DTO {
  
  constructor(modelObj) {
  }
  find(){
    // ... 
  }
}

// For these two lines of code, I refer to here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696236/module-exports-in-typescript
declare let module: any; 
(module).exports = DTO;
```

Then, using the above code, I released a NPM package, which I used in other places:

```
// MyDto.js
class MyDto extends DTO {

  constructor() {
    super(mongoose.models);
  }
}

// Using Mydto
const myDto  = new MyDto();
//This method works well in express, but this error occurs in nestjs. error message is:
// Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

Who can tell me how to write this dto? In order to achieve my goal.

Comment: ```extends value undefined is not a constructor or null``` looks like extends can't find some class to extend

Comment: Show your nestjs code