# How to write "module.exports" from javascript to typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I convert the JavaScript **module.exports** to typescript

The JavaScript code of the **module.exports** is :

```js
module.exports = {
    discord: {
        clientID: "",
        clientSecret: "",
        clientToken: "",
    },
    tokens: {
        twitchClientID: "",
        openWeatherMap: "",
    },
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module.exports in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696236/module-exports-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2):

use `export default`

```
const val = {
    discord: {
        clientID: "",
        clientSecret: "",
        clientToken: "",
    },
    tokens: {
        twitchClientID: "",
        openWeatherMap: "",
    },
};
export default val
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `export default` keyword:

```
export default {
    discord: {
        clientID: "",
        clientSecret: "",
        clientToken: "",
    },
    tokens: {
        twitchClientID: "",
        openWeatherMap: "",
    },
}
```

You can also export single elements (equivalent of `module.exports.foo = { ... }`):

```
export const foo = {
    discord: {
        clientID: "",
        clientSecret: "",
        clientToken: "",
    },
    tokens: {
        twitchClientID: "",
        openWeatherMap: "",
    },
}
```